# Slider not looping twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble figure out why my slider will not loop twice through all 3 of my slides which I have in the variable numSlides and then after the third image has faded out form the final loop, fade in the first and then stop. Any thoughts? I've hit a block on this.

```
var slide = $(".container .slide");
var slideIndex = -1;
var numSlides = 3;

function showNextSlide() {
    if (slideIndex < 2* numSlides) {
        ++slideIndex;
        slide.eq(slideIndex % slide.length)
            .fadeIn(700)
            .delay(4000)
            .fadeOut(700, showNextSlide)
            .delay(11000);
            $('.container .slide:first-child').fadeIn(700);
    }
}    

showNextSlide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wyz6c873/

Comment: Could you please update the code on Fiddle, so that I can work on it.Thanks

Comment: @subhkriti http://jsfiddle.net/wyz6c873/

Answer (score 1):

you should redefine  slideIndex

```
   function showNextSlide() {
        if (slideIndex < 2* numSlides) {
            ++slideIndex;
            slide.eq(slideIndex % slide.length)
                .fadeIn(700)
                .delay(4000)
                .fadeOut(700, showNextSlide)
                .delay(11000);
                $('.container .slide:first-child').fadeIn(700);
        } else slideIndex = -1;
    }
```